# rexecd daemon for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

How to start rexecd daemon/server on ubuntu-11.10 ?

If I try to run the command `/usr/sbin/in.rexecd` then an error appears as `rexecd: getpeername: Socket operation on non-socket`

rexecd is remote execution server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rexecd` is supposed to be run by [inetd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/inetd.8.html), [tcpd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/tcpd.8.html) or [xinetd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/xinetd.8.html) daemons. You need to check which one is installed or install one. I would recommend `xinetd` as it allows the more flexible configuration.